# How get response from setnextrequest:

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Folder
Request 1
Request 2

How can I get response from request 1, that I call in Request 2 -> prerequest script with this function postman.setNextRequest("Request 1")? I need info from response Request 1 use as varible in Request 2.

Thank you for you advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can reuse the whole response.

But you can access the response in the `Tests` of request 1 by `pm.response`, get the data you need and store them eg in an environment variable `pm.environment.set("myVariable", "some value"` and than access that variable after the request 1 has been executed `pm.environment.get("myVariable")`

Comment: Yes! This is what I need. Thank you!